# cannot edit answers once posted because mathjax doesn't render

Tags: support

haven't been on MSE for a while and i suspect something has changed which causes me the following problem:

i can post an answer. but if i attempt to edit it after posting, the mathjax no longer renders.

my knowledge of how browsers operate is *very* rudimentary. is there any simple way round this problem?

Comment: Does [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/21541/8348) match your problem?

Comment: thx Arthur, yes, sounds like the same thing. not sure how to fix it from that discussion

Comment: Well, the other question is a [meta-tag:bug] report, and so there might not be a fix right now. But I guess it's safe to close this as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: yes, fine to close